# Block inside pytest.raises context manager not getting executed

Tags: python, testing, pytest, tokenize, python-3.8

I have been writing a tokeniser for a little language I'm developing in my free time, and I want to test it with negative input. My code can raise two kinds of `Exception`s, an `IndentationError` and a `SyntaxError` and it kind of looks like this.

```py
class Tokenizer:
    def __init__(self, source:str) -> None:
        self.source = source
        ...

    def get_next_token(self) -> Token:
        """Returns the next token and advances the position pointer into self.source"""
        ...

    def tokenize(self) -> Generator[Token, None, None]:
        """Calls get_next_token until all of self.source has been scanned"
        ...
```

Then in the tests I have lists with all sorts of input. For example:

```py
SYNTAX_ERROR_SOURCES = ["(}", "[}", "{]", "a@b"] # Note that @ is not a supported operand
```

And then one of the test functions looks like this:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("source", SYNTAX_ERROR_SOURCES)
def test_tokenize_fail_syntax_error(source: str) -> None:
    with pytest.raises(SyntaxError):
        Tokenizer(source).tokenize()
```

The problem is that `tokenize` never gets called inside the context manager and I'm not sure why. I can confirm that, by running the code under a debugger. When it reaches the line, where `tokenize` gets called, it directly goes to some `pytest` code and after that the test fails with `Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'SyntaxError'>` without ever going into `tokenize`.

Also, if I execute tokenizer.py as a script with `python tokenizer.py "a@b"` then everything is fine and the program exits with a SyntaxError, as expected.

Has anyone ever come across something like this?

Comment: Try commenting out the "pytest.raises" line. Try adding some print statements, in the test, the Tokenizer `__init__` method and in tokenize() method. Are you sure SYNTAX_ERROR_SOURCES is initialized prior to this test function definition?

Comment: Commenting out the `pytest.raises` line leads to all the tests passing. SYNTAX_ERROR_SOURCES is initialised prior to the test function and the source argument has the correct value, according to the debugger. Also adding a `print` statement to tokenize further confirms that it doesn't get called, since nothing gets printed.

Comment: At this point, I usually find that the code I am testing is not the same as the code I am editing. As for adding `print` statements, adding them to the function that is not being called won't give you much help - add them to the surrounding code.

Comment: Well, I'm sure that the code I'm testing is the one I'm editing, since the `print` statements get printed for all other functions, except for the ones I'm using `pytest.raises` in. I guess, I'll open an issue on Github then. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just found out that wrapping the call to `tokenize` with `list` makes the whole thing work correctly. Would that be a bug in pytest? I don't think it's documented somewhere, that `pytest.raises` does not work with generator objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209319/discussion-between-paulmcg-and-lysandros-nikolaou).

Comment: It's not a bug in pytest - that's just how generators work. The actual code that raises the SyntaxError won't get called until you try to consume the generator returned by tokenize(). You don't have to wrap in list, just wrap in next(), which I think will better convey that you expect the first tokenization to fail.